# Prove that a planar bipartite graph is a triangle-free graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $g$ be a planar bipartite graph. Prove whether or not $g$ is a triangle-free graph.

Comment: A path in the graph passes through vertices that alternate in color, so a closed path has an even length. A triangle has 3 sides.

Comment: What does planar have to do with it?

Comment: It must be triangle-free. I don't know a good way of explaining why, though. Try drawing it and you should see why.

Comment: It doesn't have to even be planar the result is true by the definition of a bipartite graph; but students start off with planar graphs because they are easier to visualize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the informal 'proof' (formal part at bottom)

Because the graph is planar and bipartite, it essentially looks like this

\ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / ...../ \ / \ / 
\

Where I have used \ and / to denote the edges, and where they meet a vertex.  Now are there any triangles?

(if someone can edit this so that the above is a legit looking graph, feel free)

That of course isn't general enough.  Here's the formal proof

Partition your vertices into $A$ and $B$ (the bipartite partition).  Now choose one vertex $x$ which is in A (wolog), it is connected to $n$ number  of vertices $\{y_{x_1},..., y_{x_n}\}$. But there is no edge connecting $\{y_{x_i}, y_{x_j} \}$ for any $i,j$ (because the elements of $B$ are disjoint because the graph is bipartite. So the graph is triangle free.  QED

Comment: The top parts of the slashes is one group and the bottom another.   In more generality, we can have mul

Comment: Why was my answer selected as the correct one.. then quickly unselected?  It is clearly correct

Comment: Could i please have an explanation for the downvote... i clearly didn't have to even give any answer, and comments are the norm here.

Comment: Sorry i deselected because i am waiting to see other answers. It does not mean that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @user3015716 how those answers comin' along?